# How to create a TAB VIEW in Android Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-fragments

How to create a tabview, I have gone through many blogs in which they specify that tabview widget is depreciated from lv 8 but i need to create a layout which i have attached below. Can anyone guide me to design a layout like this, such that if i click on weekly this view should be displayed and another activity for today button.

[image]

Comment: Please close your question by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer that helped you most

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For implementing `TabView` you can use `ActionBar` . You can explore this [ActionBarSherLock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/). Here is the example of this [Android Working with Action Bar](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-working-with-action-bar/).

Comment: @Rat-a-tat-a-tatRatatouille that is what i wanted to know? ;-) any way i love that movie. :-)

Comment: I saw that link which you have posted but my question is if i set the tab view as mentioned in Android Working with Action Bar, whether i can create listview inside that. I mean for each tab different listview ????

Comment: @user3128481 yes you can because the swipeable view you can set your own layout inside it.

Comment: See the section named **Adding Tab Navigation** in that example you can set your own layout for your fragments which would be different for different tabs. Go through the example.

Comment: Just as an FYI, ActionBarSherlock is no longer necessary or supported for a while. Check out the website... You might be better off going with other recs

Answer (score 5):

Rather than go running off to use ActionBarSherlock, simple standard stock Android offers a tutorial and an example project on its site here.

http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/swipe-views.html

Familiarize yourself with Fragments and you should be good-to-go so long as you are comfortable already creating the layouts beneath each tab.